# Two embedded gallery in one post

Tags: plugins, gallery

I've a nice question for you.

Is there an easy way, to embed two galleries in the same post? I refer to the wordpress embedded gallery. Using a plugin of-course.

Is there outside a plugin other than [Easy Gallery Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-gallery-manager/) that can accomplish this goals?

Must I write a new plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create two different posts, each containing a different gallery. These can be drafts or private or whatever.

Then you can include their galleries into a different post by specifying their post IDs in the gallery shortcode.

`[gallery id=123]`

Comment: Nice, suggestion. That was my first inspiration. But, I need to do it seamlessy in the same admin page of the post. I'll try to modify the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [AutoNav Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/autonav/). For example, if you wanted to display the first six attached images in one place, and the remainder below, you would use the two shortcodes:

```
[autonav display=attached start=0 count=6]
...
[autonav display=attached start=6]
```

There are many more options that let you resize the thumbnails, use different table or list layouts, link to the images or the "attachment page" -- like this:

```
[autonav display="attached,page" size=400x300 count=1]
```

Or display, at random, two of the images attached to the current post:

```
[autonav display=attached count=2 order=rand]
```

You could also display the attachments to "this" page in one gallery, and the images attached to another post (let's say, with ID=509) like this:

```
[autonav display=attached]
...
[autonav display=attached postid=509]
```

Or even, display the featured thumbnail images of all the pages that are siblings to the current page (i.e., all the other child pages of the current page's parent):

```
[autonav display="images,siblings" columns=4]
```

That will create a 4-column table, with each thumbnail linking to the appropriate page.